# Не могу зайти на cabinet.ruobr.ru через requests

Tags: python, requests

хочу парсить дз со сайта, но сайт меня никак не пускает.

```
import requests


URL = 'https://cabinet.ruobr.ru/login/'
URL2 = 'https://cabinet.ruobr.ru/child/studies/journal/'


payload = {
    'username': 'log',
    'password': 'pass'
}


headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'}

with requests.Session() as c:
    c.post(URL, headers=headers, data=payload)
    r = c.get(URL2, headers=headers)
    print(r.text) #выводит страницу авторизации
```

Что надо сделать,что бы сайт меня пропустил? по кукам никак,тк не запоминает их. Через селениум все прекрасно работает.

Comment: читайте про `CSRF `. Данным способом вы не спарсите ничего

Comment: как это можно обойти?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно получить расписание вместе с домашними заданиями, используя API их мобильного приложения, используйте модуль `ruobr_api`.

```bsh
pip install ruobr_api
```

```py
from ruobr_api import Ruobr

api = Ruobr('username', 'password')
timetable = api.get_timetable("2020-12-18", "2020-12-31")

for lesson in timetable:
    if "task" in lesson:
        print(lesson)

# Пример вывода:
# {'division_subject_str': 'основной предмет', 'staff_id': 5322, 'task': [{'title': ' §13 читать', 'doc': False, 'requires_solutions': False, 'deadline': '2020-12-18', 'done': 0, 'test_id': None, 'type': 'group', 'id': 43898568}], 'time_start': '09:45:00', 'staff': 'Дашкова Марина Николаевна', 'division_subject': 1, 'time_end': '10:25:00', 'topic': 'Массовая культура. Тенденции духовной жизни современной России.', 'marks': [{'question_name': 'Ответ на уроке', 'question_id': 120240086, 'number': 1, 'question_type': 'Ответ на уроке', 'mark': '4'}], 'date': '2020-12-18', 'docs_for_lesson': [], 'id': 198726280, 'subject': 'Обществознание'}
```

Ссылка на репозиторий с исходным кодом: https://github.com/raitonoberu/ruobr_api

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]